# Repeated Expansion of Dynamic String Array Breaks When Array Size >= 3

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am working on a project for a class I am in, and I am at a loss as to why it works at first but then stops working once `arraySize` hits 3.

The point of the program is to have a list of strings, where you can add or remove elements using dynamic strings. The program should loop indefinitely until the user inputs `9` to exit.

But, once the user inputs a string while `arraySize` is 3 or above, it quits. The program is not complete, but in order to move on, I need to know what I am doing wrong.

Note: The professor doesn't want us using `vector`, and the function prototypes are the ones that were given.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

int choice, size, i, item, count, arraySize, elementsToAdd;
string array, newArray, oldArray, newElement;
bool operationSuccess;
string arr[1];

void printMenu();
void menuInputValidation(int &choice);
void inputValidation(int choice, string &newElement);
string *expand(string *oldArray, int &arraySize);
void printList(string *arr, int count);        
bool insertAtEnd(string *arr, string newElement, int arraySize);

int main()
{
    cout << "Please choose from the following menu choices" << endl;
    do
    {
        printMenu();
        cin >> choice;
        menuInputValidation(choice);
        
        //Choices
        
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            //Insert a new element(s) to the end of the list
            expand(arr, arraySize);
            cout << "Please input element to add to the end of the list." << endl << ">";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.clear();
            cin >> newElement;
            inputValidation(choice, newElement);
            operationSuccess = false;
            insertAtEnd(arr, newElement, arraySize);
            if(operationSuccess == 0)
                cout << "Error. Operation failed. " << endl;
            if(operationSuccess == 1)
                cout << endl << "Element successfully added." << endl;
        }
        
        else if(choice == 8)
        {
            //Print the contents of the list
            printList(arr, count);
        }
        else if(choice == 9)
        {
            cout << "Exiting.";
        }
        if(choice != 9)
        {
            cout << "What would you like to do next?" << endl;
        }
    }
    while(choice != 9);

    return 0;
}

//Functions

void printMenu()
{
    cout << "1) Insert a new element to the end of the list." << endl;
    cout << "2) Insert a new element at the beginning of the list." << endl;
    cout << "3) Insert an element into the list at a given index." << endl;
    cout << "4) Remove an element from the end of the list." << endl;
    cout << "5) Remove an element from the beginning of the list." << endl;
    cout << "6) Remove an element from the list at a given index." << endl;
    cout << "7) Sort the list." << endl;
    cout << "8) Print the contents of the list." << endl;
    cout << "9) Exit." << endl;
    cout << ">";
}

void menuInputValidation(int &choice)
{
    while(choice < 1 ||choice > 9)
    {
        cout << "Please input a number between 1 - 9. ";
        if(choice != 0)
            cout << "Enter 0 to see menu." << endl << ">";
        else
            cout << endl << ">";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == 0)
        {
            printMenu();
        }
    }
}

void inputValidation(int choice, string &newElement)
{
    if(choice == 1 || choice == 2)
    {    
        while(cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Please only input letters " << endl << ">";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.clear();
            cin >> newElement;
        }
    }
    else if (choice)
    {
        
    }
}

string *expand(string *oldArray, int &arraySize)
{
    arraySize += 1;
    string *newArray = new string[arraySize];
    newArray = oldArray;
    return newArray;
    delete[] newArray;
}

void printList(string *arr, int count)
{
    for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        cout << *(arr + i) << endl;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Press enter to continue. ";
    cin.get();
}

bool insertAtZero(string *arr, string newElement, int count)
{
    return operationSuccess;
}

bool insertAtEnd(string *newArray, string newElement, int arraySize)
{
    cout << ">" << arraySize << "<";
    *(newArray + arraySize - 1) = newElement;
    return operationSuccess = true;
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use `std::vector<std::string>` please!

Comment: `return newArray;  delete[] newArray;` The delete here will never be executed and that's a good thing since it will free the memory you return.

Comment: And before the "I can't use std::string or std::vector" is stated, both of those classes, std::vector and std::string, have been part of standard C++ for **24 years** now.  The way these 20+ year parts of C++ seem to be treated as if they are recent add-ons by a third-party somewhere. -- *Note: The professor doesn't want us using vectors* -- Another professor is contributing to new C++ programmers being turned off from C++, and instead go to Python or some other language.  Great.

Comment: I am attempting to copy the old array into the new one while retaining the empty space at the end of the new array. Honestly not really sure why the delete is there but she did tell us to use it. My goal is to deallocate the old memory.

Comment: `string arr[1];` -- If your code attempts to issue a `delete[]` on `arr`, the behavior is undefined.  The `arr` was not dynamically allocated using `new[]`.

Comment: `expand(arr, arraySize);` -- You cannot expand a non-dynamic array -- arrays are fixed in size.  This is exactly what I was referring to in the last comment.

Comment: Stack Overflow Usage note: Do what you can to focus your code example on the bug you are hunting before asking a question. If you drop 200 lines of code, odds are really good that folk will write answers about a totally different bug. Use [mre] for inspiration.

Comment: **Side note :**  Expanding the array size by one is very inefficient as you need a memory allocation each and every time you add an item. Usually, you want something more exponential like doubling the size each time your array is full.

Comment: Typically I would, this is what the professor wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Your main bug in your expand function is here: `newArray = oldArray;` This sets the newArray pointer to point to the same location as the oldArray pointer and in the process it throws away the pointer to the new array you just allocated which leaks the memory allocated because there is no way to free that allocation since you no longer have a pointer that points to it.

Instead of setting newArray to point to the same location as oldArray you need to copy the elements from the oldArray to the new array.

```cpp
string *expand(string *oldArray, int &arraySize)
{
    string *newArray = new string[arraySize+1];

    // Copy the array elements from the old to the new
    for(int i=0; i < arraySize;++i) {
      newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }

    arraySize++;
    delete[] oldArray;
    return newArray;
}
```

You had an additional bug in the last 2 lines of expand():

```cpp
    return newArray;  
    delete[] newArray;
```

The delete here will never be executed because once execution hits a return the function is finished. This is a good thing since if it would have executed the `delete[] newArray;` this would have freed the same memory you return a pointer to.

As @PaulMcKenzie just commented the initial `string arr[1];` can not be used to pass to this function since this allocation was not allocated by new[] you can't use it with your expand function.

Instead you need:

```cpp
string* arr = new string[1];
```

Instead of:

```cpp
string arr[1];
```

Comment: I think I just fixed that with the comment from @PaulMcKenzie. I did not scan the entire program when I started writing this.

Comment: Note: While for a new learner doing this the laborious way is educational, in real code I'd probably replace the loop with: `std::move(oldArray, oldArray+arraySize, newArray);`, which both removes the need to write the loop manually and initializes the new values via move assignment rather than copy assignment, which, at least for `std::string`, is `noexcept`, so you don't have to worry about exceptions anywhere but the `new` expression (plus, if the strings are large enough that the small string optimization doesn't apply, it could be a *lot* faster).

Comment: Agreed, I intentionally tried to keep it to the level of the person asking.

Comment: Thank you very much, pointers don't make inherent sense to me and I have been very confused throughout most of the coding process with them. You did a good job of explaining it so I won't make a similar mistake :)

Comment: Now when I run the program it is quitting after I input the choice of what to do next no matter what option I select.

Comment: You may have to debug in a debugger like Visual Studio or gdb to narrow down the source. There is a lot of code to go through here. I believe I fixed the main problem.